# What is the best way to check if values multiple values in certain ways match?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a tic tac toe game, and for it to work I need to have a function to check if there are 3 in a row.

the grid is like this

```
012
345
678
```

It means `012`, `345`, `678`, `036`, `147`, `258`, `048`, `246` are all possible combinations.
I tried:

```
if(clickedCells[0] && clickedCells[1] && clickedCells[2] !== "" && clickedCells[0] === clickedCells[1] && clickedCells[0] === clickedCells[2]){
        done();
}
```

But it doesn't work because it is invalid.

I would like to know the best way to get such a thing working, because I have never had to so much if-statements in a row and it looks like a total mess if I check each thing independently.

Comment: Is 047 a typo? Should be 048

Comment: And a little more of your soucecode wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @HerbalMart I can post everything, but I just don't know what there is more to know about this. clickedCells is an array which contains either nothing "", X or O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store every valid combination in an array.

```
var combinations = new Array([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]);
```

Now instead of setting up an if-condition for a single combination you can loop over the entire array and check your board at the position specified.

```
if (board[combinations[a][0]] == id && board[combinations[a][1]] == id && board[combinations[a][2]] == id)
```

Here's the compelte example:

```js
var board = new Array(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
);

function check(id) {
  var ret = null;
  var combinations = new Array([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]);
  var found;
  for (var a = 0; a < combinations.length; a++) {
    if (board[combinations[a][0]] == id && board[combinations[a][1]] == id && board[combinations[a][2]] == id) {
      ret = combinations[a];
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
console.log(check(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clickedCells[0] && clickedCells[1] && clickedCells[2] !== ""
```

This code seems to compares 3 boolean variables to an empty string.
But if the clickedCells contains strings the proper way to compare would be

```
clickedCells[0] + clickedCells[1] + clickedCells[2] !== ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multidimensional array which contain all the possible combinations.

```
let arr = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]....]
```

Then use `some()` with `every()`. Consider that you array is called `game`. So you can check for winning like below.

```
arr.some(x => x.every(a => game[a] === game[x[0]]))
```

#### Explanation:

`some()` is array method which takes a callback and checks if atleast one of the element of array matches the condition. So here different array means `x` will be

```
[0,1,2],[3,4,5]...
```

Now for each of the nested array we need to check if they are same in the game which is 1D array representing tic tac toe game.

```
x.every(a => game[a] === game[x[0]])
```

The above line checks for each of the nested array if any one that have all same elements when they are used and indexes for game board.

Answer (score -1):

> It means 012, 345, 678, 036, 147, 258, 048, 246 are all possible combinations

So just hard-code that combinations

```
const winningSets = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], ...];
return winningSets.some((winningSet) =>
    winningSet.every((cell) => cell === 'O'));
```

See, typically we would like avoid hard-coding values but for this specific case index-based math would look complicated and less readable. Especially when matrix is represented as linear array.